# How to look up a word in the Mac OS X dictionary with AppleScript?

Tags: dictionary, macos, applescript

How can I look up a word in the Mac OS X dictionary through AppleScript?

Comment: do you mean the apple script library or the dictionary as in definition of a word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dictionary.app is not scriptable but it supports its own URL scheme, which you can exploit from AppleScript:

```
open location "dict://mandolin"
```